# How to map JsonPatchDocument using Mapster?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mapster

### I have my model:

```
public class Membership  
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required] public int PeriodType { get; set; }
    
    [Required] public int Duration { get; set; }
    
    [Required] public int TerminationPeriod { get; set; }
    
    [Required] public float InstallmentPrice { get; set; }
}
```

### And my Dto:

```
public class MembershipDto
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int PeriodType { get; set; }
    
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    
    public int TerminationPeriod { get; set; }
    
    public float InstallmentPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework and JsonPatchDocument to make PATCH operation in my API, the code is following:

```
public async Task<MembershipDto> Handle(EditMembershipCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var membershipEntity = await _dbContext
        .Memberships
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == request.Id);

    if (membershipEntity is null)
        throw new NullReferenceException($"Membership [Id: {request.Id}] not found");

    var editedMembership = request.NewMembershipDto.Adapt<JsonPatchDocument<Membership>>(); //request.NewMembershipDto is type of JsonPatchDocument<MembershipDto>

    editedMembership.ApplyTo(membershipEntity, ModelState);
    _ = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    var membershipDto = editedMembership.Adapt<MembershipDto>();

    return membershipDto;
}
```

As an output I get the following information:

```
ProblemDetails.ProblemDetailsMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  Mapster.CompileException: Error while compiling
  source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1[AgreementApi.Dtos.MembershipDto]
  destination=Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument`1[AgreementApi.Models.Membership]
  type=Map
   ---> Mapster.CompileException: Error while compiling
  source=Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver
  destination=Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver
  type=Map
   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No default constructor for type 'IContractResolver', please use 'ConstructUsing' or 'MapWith'
     at Mapster.Utils.DynamicTypeGenerator.CreateTypeForInterface(Type interfaceType)
     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
     at Mapster.Utils.DynamicTypeGenerator.GetTypeForInterface(Type interfaceType)
     at Mapster.Adapters.RecordTypeAdapter.CreateInstantiationExpression(Expression source, Expression destination, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateInstantiationExpression(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.RecordTypeAdapter.CreateInlineExpression(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateInlineExpressionBody(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateExpressionBody(Expression source, Expression destination, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptFunc(CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateInlineMapExpression(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, MapType mapType, CompileContext context, MemberMapping mapping)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptExpressionCore(Expression source, Type destinationType, CompileArgument arg, MemberMapping mapping, Expression destination)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptExpression(Expression source, Type destinationType, CompileArgument arg, MemberMapping mapping, Expression destination)
     at Mapster.Adapters.ClassAdapter.CreateInlineExpression(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateInlineExpressionBody(Expression source, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateExpressionBody(Expression source, Expression destination, CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.Adapters.BaseAdapter.CreateAdaptFunc(CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(CompileArgument arg)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateMapExpression(TypeTuple tuple, MapType mapType)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.CreateDynamicMapExpression(TypeTuple tuple)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.<GetDynamicMapFunction>b__66_0[TDestination](TypeTuple tuple)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.<>c__DisplayClass55_0`1.<AddToHash>b__0(TypeTuple types)
     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.AddToHash[T](ConcurrentDictionary`2 hash, TypeTuple key, Func`2 func)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig.GetDynamicMapFunction[TDestination](Type sourceType)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt[TDestination](Object source, TypeAdapterConfig config)
     at Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt[TDestination](Object source)
     at Fitverse.AgreementApi.Handlers.EditMembershipHandler.Handle(EditMembershipCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /Users/wonsu/Repositories/Fitverse/Fitverse.AgreementApi/Handlers/EditMembershipHandler.cs:line 34
     at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
     at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
     at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
     at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
     at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
     at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
     at Fitverse.AgreementApi.Controllers.SettingsController.EditMembership(Int32 id, JsonPatchDocument`1 membershipDto) in /Users/wonsu/Repositories/Fitverse/Fitverse.AgreementApi/Controllers/SettingsController.cs:line 52
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails.ProblemDetailsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I know that the issue is in this line of code:

```
var editedMembership = request.NewMembershipDto.Adapt<JsonPatchDocument<Membership>>();
```

But I don't know how to change it to properly map it to desired type. Could you help me? :)

I know that at the end I should probably get the membership from DB again, map it and return it instead of just mapping editedMembership, but I'll fit it after dealing with this mapping issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the mapping of IContractResolver helps resolve the issue.

```
   private static TypeAdapterConfig GetConfiguredMappingConfig()
        {
            var config = TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings;
            IList<IRegister> registers = config.Scan(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            config.Apply(registers);

            config.NewConfig<IContractResolver, IContractResolver>()
              .ConstructUsing(src => new DefaultContractResolver());

            return config;
        }
```